# How to convert the map to map of map i.e nested map using Streams

Tags: java-stream

I have below input Map and want to convert it into Map of Map i.e. Map> using java streams, any help would be appericiable

```
Map<String, Object> objectmetainfo = new HashMap();
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.id", "id");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.title", "title");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.description", "description");

objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.user.id", "id");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.user.firstName", "firstName");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.user.lastName", "lastName");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.user.email", "email");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.user.phone", "phone");

objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.userSupervisor.id", "id");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.userSupervisor.firstName", "firstName");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.userSupervisor.lastName", "lastName");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.userSupervisor.email", "email");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.userDetails.userSupervisor.phone", "phone");

--------- many more ---------


objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.user_id", "id");
objectmetainfo.put("metainfo.user_name", "name");
```

I want to convert this map to Map as below :

1. Those records which contains the prefix **metainfo.userDetails** e.g. "metainfo.userDetails.user.id", "id", we have to remove the prefix metainfo.userDetails, next word will be considered as key for map, in above case **user** will be the key of map and rest thing as key value pair of inner map
   E.g.:- Below is outputmap for all the records which contains **metainfo.userDetails** prefix

```
{"user":{"id":"id", "firstName":"firstName", "lastName":"lastName", "email":"email", "phone":"phone"}, "userSupervisor":{"id":"id", "firstName":"firstName", "lastName":"lastName", "email":"email", "phone":"phone}}
```

2. Records which don't contain the **metainfo.userDetails** and only contain "metainfo." prefix those need to be populated in map under key "additional"
   E.g.:-

```
{"additional":{"user_id":"user_id", "user_name":"user_name"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Pair (import javafx.util.Pair;) to get the `Pair<String, Pair<String, Object>>`

The idea is very simple, to first get entrySet of Map, and then make individual Pair based on the conditions. 
Using GroupingBy to combine the results (to get Map>) and collecting it into Map.

```
  Map<String, Map<String, Object>> answer =
            objectmetainfo.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(e-> makePair(e))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e-> e.getKey(), Collectors.toMap(e-> e.getValue().getKey(), e-> e.getValue().getValue()) ));
```

Make Pair Function :

```
    private static Pair<String, Pair<String, Object>> makePair(Map.Entry<String, Object> mapEntry){

    final String[] s = mapEntry.getKey().split("\\.");

  return
            mapEntry.getKey().contains("metainfo.userDetails.") ?  new Pair(s[2],
                    new Pair(s[3], mapEntry.getValue())) :
                    new Pair("additional",
                            new Pair(s[1], mapEntry.getValue()))
            ;
}
```

Splitting key into "." (regex "//.") and then making pairs as per conditions.

PS: Please give meaningful names to the variables.

Comment: "Grouping by" will group the nested map as per your conditions which is Key in this pair. Welcome, Tarun. Really appreciate the upvote. :)

Comment: I was trying with some example, when i do below .map(e-> new Pair(e, e)) then my code shows compilation error in the collector. But when i move pair constructor in separate method i.e. makePair then it is working fine, do you have any idea?                   Also, when i post new question in stackoverflow, it shows -3 points, not sure if there's any issue with my question

Comment: ``` ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add(12);
        System.out.println(test.stream().map(e-> new 
         Pair(e,e)).collect(Collectors.toList()));```
It is working fine for me. Can you test again and check the version of java you are using. 
I too am new to Stack Overflow, people down point it when the question is not useful or clear.